# Drupal 6: onkeyup event to a custom form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

How can I add a onkeyup event to a custom form field in Drupal 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drupal forum threads [How do I add an "onblur" javascript event handler to a form field...](http://drupal.org/node/333686) and
[jQuery event not firing](http://drupal.org/node/303754) cover this very topic. In short, you should use jQuery to inject your javascript into the form.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has the drupal_add_js() function which it uses to add javascript files to a page. This is the first step, after that you will have jQuery available to use, so doing this should work for you just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form-element-id").keyup(function () {
        // Do your things here.
    })
}
```

You should note that this is more of a javascript/jQuery question than it is a Drupal question. You only need Drupal to add the js file itself, the rest is pure javascript with jQuery